# Andorid Wear - Start Mobile Service on Watch Face Set

Tags: android, google-api, android-service, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

How do I start a standard `Service` on my mobile device from a watch face? Would I need to use the Message API? If so, what would be the correct way of doing this? I currently only start the `Service` on the mobile's boot and when I open the config activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to use the Message API. You'll find it well documented at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer; if you subclass `WearableListenerService` on the handheld, it will start automatically when a message is sent from the watch. This could be your existing service (just change it from `extends Service` to `extends WearableListenerService`), or you could leave your existing service unchanged and start it from the new `WearableListenerService` when a message arrives.